# Android create drop down menu

Tags: android, menu

Does anyone know how I can create some sort of drop down or pop up on a page so that i can then go to any page from the page that i am on ?

For example i have a menu page but when i select an option i want to be able to navigate to another page instead of going back to the menu

```
public class PopUpMenu extends Activity {


 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.test);
 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu, menu);
    return true;



}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.location:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyLocation.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        return true;
    case R.id.search:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Search.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        return true;
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddSite.class);
        startActivity(intent3);
        return true;
//      case R.id.help:
//          Intent intent4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Help.class);
//          startActivity(intent4);
//          return true;    
    case R.id.exit:    
        Intent intent5 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent5.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent5.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent5);
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/location" android:title="My Location" />
<item android:id="@+id/search" android:title="Search" />
<item android:id="@+id/add" android:title="Add Site" />
<item android:id="@+id/help" android:title="Help" />
<item android:id="@+id/exit" android:title="Exit" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, here is a good tutorial for you: [Activity Testing](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html)

You have a couple of samples on the [developers.android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) site.
The most comprehensive is the [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) which includes a wide specter of tools and techniques.

Then, for your purpose, the widget is named [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html), and a demo of it is [Spinner Test](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SpinnerTest/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

The menu (in XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/food" android:title="Food" />
<item android:id="@+id/other" android:title="Other" />
</menu>
```

To set the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

To handle switching activities:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.food:
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getContext(), Food.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
        return true;
    case R.id.other:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getContext(), Other.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: i basically have a menu i can select an option eg food then on the food page i may want to go to another page but instead of pressing back to go to the menu i want to press a button to get a pop up where i can then chose which page to go to next

Comment: So... let me see if I'm understanding you correctly.  In your menu, the user selects the "food" option, which starts the food page.  The on the food page, the user presses menu and selects another option, say "other," which takes them to the "other" page, and so on...  Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, the way I would do this is create your menu with all options on it: "food," "other," etc.  Then when the user clicks an option, call startActivity to start the corresponding activity (switch statement based on what option the user selected).  Does that make sense?  I can post example code if you want.

Comment: also menu in the xml file isnt recognised

Comment: Each activity (food, other, etc.) will be its own unique class that extends Activity.  Also, when you create your xml file in res/menu, choose menu from the list of options.

Comment: i dont seem to have a menu option in xml

Comment: Create a folder in /res called menu.  So then you have a folder /res/menu.  Right click it, and select New --> Android XML File.  Name it whatever you want, and under "Root Element:" select "menu."  Then open the XML file and add the items as shown above.

Comment: how would the menu then be displayed on the screen ?

Comment: Just like any other normal menu: a popup on the bottom of the screen (or top for ICS).

Comment: it appears as a blank screen, ive created a button so that when selected it brings up the menu but nothing happens

Comment: When are you getting the blank screen?

Comment: when i click the button it goes to another screen which is blank

Comment: also not sure if content view should be this    setContentView(R.menu.popupmenu);
as it seems to complain about it

Comment: i think i will have to revert to using buttons instead

Comment: thanks but im just going to use buttons as its an easier options but thanks anyway

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into the question and/or answer, or even post new answers with new details if that is warranted. The comment section of a question/answer is only meant for relevant information regarding the actual post at hand, like mistakes, requests for more details, etc. not for long discussions even though they may be helpful to the people involved. If you need to continue this discussion, consider taking it to a chat room instead.